How to find an integer value for 'c' that results in integer solutions for 'a' and 'b' in a system of linear equations?
I’m trying to solve matrices in C. The equation I’m solving is:
4a = c          4  0 -1 0             1  0 -0.25 0
10a + b = 4c -> 10 1 -4 0 R1 -> R1/4  10 1 -4    0
2b = 3c         0  2 -3 0             0  2 -3    0         
------------------------------------------------------>
               1 0 -0.25 0                 1 0 -0.25 0
R2-> R2 - 10R  0 1 -1.5  0 R3 -> R3 – 2R2  0 1  1.5  0
               0 2 -3    0                 0 0  0    0

i.e., a - 0.25c=0, b - 1.5c=0
i.e., a = 0.25c, b = 1.5c
The third row of the matrix has become null, which indicates that we have a redundant equation or a solution with a free variable that we can choose an integer so that we get the result of ‘a’ and ‘b’ as integers. How to apply the logic to find this integer value this row in order solve ‘a’ and ‘b’?
I tested and verified that the value for c is 4, but I don't want to have to do int c = 4.
code below...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 3  // Number of equations

void print_matrix(double matrix[N][N+1]) {
    printf("Matriz:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= N; j++) {
            printf("%.2f\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void gauss_elimination(double matrix[N][N+1], double solution[N]) {
    int i, j, k;
    
    // Elimination phase
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
        //Partial pivoting
        for (k = i + 1; k < N; k++) {
            if (fabs(matrix[i][i]) < 1e-10) {
                for (j = 0; j <= N; j++) {
                    double temp = matrix[i][j];
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[k][j];
                    matrix[k][j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Gaussian elimination
        for (k = i + 1; k < N; k++) {
            double factor = matrix[k][i] / matrix[i][i];
            for (j = i; j <= N; j++) {
                matrix[k][j] -= factor * matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    print_matrix(matrix);
    
    // Back replacement phase
    for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        solution[i] = matrix[i][N];
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            solution[i] -= matrix[i][j] * solution[j];
        }
        solution[i] /= matrix[i][i];
    }
}

int main() {
    double matrix[N][N+1] = {
        {4.00, 0.00, -1.00, 0.00},
        {10.00, 1.00, -4.00, 0.00},
        {0.00, 2.00, -3.00, 0.00}
    };

    double solution[N];

    // Solve the system
    gauss_elimination(matrix, solution);
    
    printf("Solutions:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("%c = %.2f\n",'a' + i, solution[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

Result I got:
Matriz:
4.00    0.00    -1.00   0.00    
0.00    1.00    -1.50   0.00    
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    

Solutions:
a = -nan
b = -nan
c = -nan
=== Code Execution Successful ===
  a     b        c      d
a 4.00  0.00    -1.00   0.00 //=    1/4 = 0,25
b 0.00  1.00    -1.50   0.00 //=    1,50/1 = 1,50
c 0.00  2.00    -3.00   0.00 //= NULL

Notice that it obtained -nan because I still haven’t been able to think of a logic to find an integer value for the null row such that this value operating by the unknowns above results in integer values.
Section updated as discussed in the comments.
In the back substitution phase:
solution[i] -= matrix[i][j] * solution[j];
When we have a null line it’s the same as doing
solution[i] -= matrix[i][j] * 0;
Which then gets, -NaN because solution[i] /= matrix[i][i];
Will be the same as 0 /= matrix[i][i];
How to make for example a for(intPositv) to go through solution[i] /= matrix[i][i] * intPositv with positive values and stop only when the solutions solution[i] /= matrix[i][i]; are integers? I’ve already made an if-else condition to enter the back substitution phase in case there is a null line.
int null_row = -1; //  Indicator for null line not found
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int is_null = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (fabs(matrix[i][j]) > 1e-10) {
                is_null = 0; // The line is not null
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_null) {
            null_row = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (null_row != -1) {
        // Determine the variable corresponding to the null 
        char null_variable = 'a' + null_row;
        printf("Line Null line variable: %c\n", null_variable);
        // Back substitution phase
        for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (fabs(matrix[i][i]) < 1e-10) {
                // Handle special case where matrix[i][i] is zero
                solution[i] = 0.0; 
                // -Set the variable to zero
            } else {
                solution[i] = matrix[i][N];
                for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
                    solution[i] -= matrix[i][j] * 4.0;
                    //Here I multiplied by 4 is where the problem is. 
                   //How to make a loop go through positive integers until the result of 
                 //solution[i] /= matrix[i][i]; are integers? Or, I don’t know, some 
               //other way to get the value 4?
                }
                solution[i] /= matrix[i][i];
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("There is no null line.\n");
    }

Also test with the array…
        //n = 5
        {1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, -2.00, 0.00},
        {1.00, 0.00, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00},
        {3.00, 3.00, -3.00, -2.00, -1.00, 0.00},
        {0.00, 2.00, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00},
        {0.00, 1.00, 0.00, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00}

That has the equation:
matrix reduced to row reduced echelon form as
a = 2e                    1 0 0 0 -2 0
a = c                     0 1 0 0 -1 0
3a + 3b = 3c + 2d + e     0 0 1 0 -2 0
2b = c                    0 0 0 1 -1 0
b = d                     0 0 0 0  0 0 

Here rank(A) = 4 = rank ([A, B]) < n = 5, Thus the system (5) has
infinitely many solutions. Let one variable 5 is independent variable, it 
takes any real number. Let  = , Equations from the matrix (6) are as:  
From first row of matrix (6): 1 − 25 = 0 i.e.  =  =   
From second row of matrix (6): 2 − 5 = 0 i.e.  =  =   
From third row of matrix (6): 3 − 25 = 0 i.e.  = () = () =   
From fourth row of matrix (6): 4 − 5 = 0 i.e.  =  =   

I appreciate any help or suggestions to solve this formula interpretation problem

This is more a math question than a C question.  You might want to brush up on your linear algebra.  If you have a singular matrix (i.e., determinant zero), then there are either no solutions, or an infinite number of solutions.  If there are an infinite number, then you can try setting one of the variables to some fixed value (e.g. zero), but keep in mind some values may result in a new singular matrix, i.e. some values may not work.

@TomKarzes Can you mark these tags for me? matrix, algebra-linear and mathematics
I don't have enough points.

a=b=c=0 is a solution. If there's another, there are infinitely many solutions.

@SimonGoater, hat’s what I said, there are infinite solutions. In other words, the null line is an independent variable, which accepts any real number. I have to think of a logic that tests an integer value for the null variable which solves the lines above in a way to obtain integer results for the lines above the null line. For example: a = 0.25c, b = 1.5c, if we consider the integer real value ‘1’ for ‘c’, we will not get ‘a’ and ‘b’ integers. If we consider the value ‘2’ for c we get: a = 0.25c, b = 1.5c -> a = 0.25(2) = 0.5, b = 1.5(2) = 3.

For ‘b’ we find an integer value considering c = 2, but not ‘a’, so it is not valid to assume c = 2. But if we consider 4 for c we get a = 1 and ‘b’ = 6. How to automate this?

For any integer a, you have b = 6a and c = 4a as an all integer solution. What are you trying to find?

@SimonGoater In the back substitution phase, solution[i] -= matrix[i][j] * solution[j]; when we have a null line it’s the same as doing solution[i] -= matrix[i][j] * 0 which then gets, -NaN because solution[i] /= matrix[i][i]; will be the same as 0 /= matrix[i][i]; How to make for example a for(intPositv) to go through solution[i] /= matrix[i][i] * intPositv with positive values and stop only when the solutions solution[i] /= matrix[i][i]; are integers? I’ve already made an if-else condition to enter the back substitution phase in case there is a null line.

@SimonGoater I edited the question based on the comment above, see.
